# C# + File.OpenRead(path_to_file)

Tags: c#, file, iis-7

I am developing a HTML5 based WebApp being hosted in IIS7. This webapp sends requests to webservices being hosted in IIS7.

The service initialization looks up for a specific file e.g: "appfile.txt" as

`FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("appfile.txt"); // opens file for reading.`

This call when run as a console application looks up in the project\bin or output directory and able to locate the specified file.

But the same hosted in IIS7 looks up in "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appfile.txt".

Are there any configuration item having used in web.config locates the file from the Bin directory of the IIS7 application and not anywhere else?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx

Comment: Use Server.MapPatch(string) to map your ISS app to it's folder

Comment: What type of application? You can't host a Console app on IIS.

Comment: Henk Holterman Yes, I agree that a console application cannot be hosted as such as a web app. I am not trying to do so either. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1):

If the app file is in your web application folder, try using Server.MapPath to get The location of the file relative to the root of the web app:

```
File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/appfile.txt"))
```

That should work. You probably need to set up the appfile.txt properties so it is copied to the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create your own section in the web.config file to grab the file path that you want. It doesn't need to have been predefined. Then just use any XML reader you want.

Alternatively, you can make a .resx file very easily in Visual Studio and just populate the path there as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your valuable comments, I could resolve this issue myself using the following code snippets

`string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;`

string[] labs = File.ReadAllLines(path + "/appfile.txt");

This bit of code allows me to read the file contents without any issues.